# Updated Information Requested | Craft CMS & MariaDB

Tags: database, craft-features

Is Craft stable atop MariaDB? The last update concerning MariaDB was October of 2014.

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange! Please consider accepting Brad's answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

We currently have no open tickets or known issues with MariaDB.

Fun fact: according to our logs roughly 15% of Craft installs are running some version of MariaDB.